# ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series - trying to fix values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

can anybody help me with this?

I got the following dataframe to work on:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPeOi.png)

The **SEGSTART** column means the exactly day and time the client called. If this client called two times or more within the last 7 days it must be considered as a **RECALL_7d** (value = 1). If not, the **RECALL_7d** value must be set to 0.

However, the RECALL_7d Series contains some mistakes since sometimes it consideres the client as a recall and sometimes it doesn't. I need to fix that and I did this:

1. First i created a column called **days** to count the difference between the segstart from line i and line i+1:

   df['days'] = df.SEGSTART.diff().apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(1,'D')).fillna(0).astype('int64')

The code above returned me the following dataframe. As it is possible to see, it contais an "error" since the days value for index 6 should be 0. So, to fix that, I tried to do this:

```
size = len(df['Client_id'])
df['days'] = np.nan

for i in range (size-1):

    if df.loc[i+1, 'Client_id'] == df.loc[i, 'Client_id']:
        df.loc[i+1, 'days'] = df.loc[:i+1, 'SEGSTART'].diff().apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).fillna(0).astype('int64')

    else:
        df.loc[i+1, 'days'] = 0
```

So i got this error:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
5
6     if df.loc[i+1, 'Client_id'] == df.loc[i, 'Client_id']:
----> 7         df.loc[i+1, 'days'] = df.loc[:i+1, 'SEGSTART'].diff().apply(lambda x: x/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).fillna(0).astype('int64')
8
9     else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in **setitem**(self, key, value)
668
669         iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 670         iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
671
672     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
1640
1641             if isinstance(value, ABCSeries):
-> 1642                 value = self._align_series(indexer, value)
1643
1644             info_idx = indexer[info_axis]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _align_series(self, indexer, ser, multiindex_indexer)
1952             return ser.reindex(ax)._values
1953
-> 1954         raise ValueError("Incompatible indexer with Series")
1955
1956     def _align_frame(self, indexer, df: ABCDataFrame):

ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAJAw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_datetime` over the `DATA` column to enable handling and comparison between dates and timedeltas. Then, use `groupby('Client_id')` and sort the `DATA` values (if not already sorted), this will ease the recall computation for each individual client. Using `diff`, compare to a 7 days time period (`pd.Timedelta(7, 'D')`) and define if this is considered a recall. Rebuild the original dataframe with `pd.concat` and `sort_index()`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df['DATA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATA'])

full_df = []
for n, g in df.groupby('Client_id'):
    g['DATA'] = g.DATA.sort_values()
    g['recall_7d'] = (g.DATA.diff() < pd.Timedelta(7, 'D')).astype(int)
    full_df.append(g)

df_out = pd.concat(full_df).sort_index()
print(df_out)
```

Output from *df_out*

```py
      Client_id                 SEGSTART       DATA  recall_7d
0   38034991852  2021-01-08 20:15:05.000 2021-01-08          0
1   38034991852  2021-01-27 19:57:49.000 2021-01-27          0
2   38034991852  2021-01-27 19:37:33.000 2021-01-27          1
3   38034991852  2021-01-27 22:08:58.000 2021-01-27          1
4   38034991852  2021-02-01 10:45:00.000 2021-02-01          1
5   38034991852  2021-02-01 10:55:53.000 2021-02-01          1
6   11111111111  2021-02-03 10:15:05.000 2021-02-03          0
7   11111111111  2021-02-06 20:23:07.000 2021-02-06          1
8   11111111111  2021-02-07 08:54:05.000 2021-02-07          1
9   11111111111  2021-02-07 20:17:05.000 2021-02-07          1
10  11111111111  2021-02-13 16:25:00.000 2021-02-13          1
11  11111111111  2021-02-28 17:19:23.000 2021-02-28          0
```